# Convolution of two signals with constrained output measuring unit

Tags: python, numpy, math, statistics

I'm programming in Python and I have two signals, a rectangular signal **f(t)** and a distribution function **g(t)** (e.g. normal distribution, log-normal distribution etc.). Both signals are defined over time (x-axis) with a resolution of 0.001 s and the measure of the rectangle is in pulses per second (1/s, y-axis). Both functions shall be convolved, whereby the unit of the result (y-axis) has to be again pulses per second for the subsequent calculations. The original domain of definition in which the results make sense is 0-250 1/s (or at least not much higher). Since I'm programming in Python, **f(t)** is just an array of ones, multiplied with a respective amplitude. I read in the literature, that **g(t)** has to be a PDF for my sort of calculations, so I normalized it to its area.

The specific background is, that **g(t)** is a time delay profile whose influence on the original signal **f(t)** shall be investigated. This means, I want to find out in which way the shape of **f(t)** is altered and which impact that has on the subsequent calculations.

**My first question is:** can I convolve these two signals without any further considerations, or do I have to transform the rectangle at first into a PDF as well?

**My second problem is:** after the convolution, what measure does the result have? Lets say I convolved the PDF of **g(t)** with the original **f(t)** ... is the resulting unit simply 1/s again? If not, how do I convert it into a signal with the unit 1/s?

The thing is, I tested both approaches *case1* **PDF(f(t)) * g(t)** and *case2* **PDF(f(t)) * PDF(g(t))**. Both results are way to high as that it would make any sense for the subsequent computations. Let me give you an example:

time resolution = 1 ms

Amplitude **f(t)** = 250 1/s

duration **f(t)** = 1.2 s

duration **g(t)** = 0.18 s

In *case1* the resulting maximal amplitude of the convolution product would be slightly less than 250k. One solution might be to divide this result by 1000 (the time resolution, because this is the parameter to which I normalized the PDF). So in the end the amplitude would be between 0-250 again. But I don't know if this is right, since this is more or less like I would convolve f(t) with the probability mass function of g(t) (division and multiplication before and after the convolution with the time resolution would cancel each other out) ... Whereas *case2* would give me an amplitude of ~833. Here I don't know how to regain 1/s.

Does anyone have an idea, or do you need at first further information?

Any help will be much appreciated!

PS: If this question doesn't fit into this stackexchange forum, then please tell me where I should ask it!

---

**EDIT:** Included code snippet for the above description.

```
#%% import

import numpy as np


#%% definitions

def AD(d, a):
    return d*np.exp(-d/a)/a**2


#%% calculate pdf of "g(t)"

# parameters
a = 0.013

# domain of definition
t_min = 1e-12
t_max = 0.5
t_step = 0.001
t_range = np.arange(t_min,t_max,t_step)

# original + pdf
distr = AD(t_range,a)
distr_pdf = distr/(distr.sum()*t_step)

# reduce the array (optimize processing time)
for x in np.arange(0, len(distr_pdf)):
    if np.round(distr_pdf[0:x+1].sum()*t_step,5) >= 1:
        distr_pdf = distr_pdf[0:x+1]
        break


#%% calculate rectangle "f(t)"

# parameters
length_rect = 1200
intensity = 250

# original + pdf
rect = np.ones(length_rect) * intensity
rect_pdf = rect/(rect.sum()*t_step)


#%% convolution case1

result1 = np.convolve(distr_pdf,rect)


#%% convolution case2

result2 = np.convolve(distr_pdf,rect_pdf)
```

Comment: This would probably benefit from some code to illustrate what you're doing, and possibly a narrowing of scope (one question at a time). If you're using specialized third-party python modules, it might help to add them to the tags.

Comment: @glibdud Added the code. Regarding the questions ... well both are relevant, but since the first question has an impact on the second problem, the first question should be solved first. Otherwise, I don't use any third-party modules.

Comment: numpy is a third-party module. I've added that for you.

Comment: I'm pretty sure if f and g are normalized so their mass = 1 each, then convolution(f, g) has mass = 1 also. I don't know if it goes the other way -- i.e. I don't know if convolution(f, g) has mass = 1 and f has mass = 1 implies g has mass = 1. About measurement units, I'm pretty sure if f and g are discretized to the same resolution (e.g. both 1 Hz, 10 Hz, whatever), then convolution(f, g) will have that same resolution again. I don't know, without investigating, what's the resolution of convolution(f, g) when f and g are discretized to different resolutions. Hope this helps in some way.

Comment: @RobertDodier First of all, thank you for your answer! But I'm not quite sure what you're trying to tell me with the "mass = 1" part. Are you implying, that it's only allowed to convolve two PDFs, or probability mass functions respectively? Because that's what I'm trying to find out with my first question. I'm trying to figure out, whether I'm solely allowed to convolve two PDFs (that would mean I have to convert my rectangle into a PDF as well), or whether the approach with the convolution of the PDF and the original rectangle is OK.

Comment: @RobertDodier Now the second part of your post. Maybe I'm misinterpreting your comment but it sounds like you're refering the measuring units to the x-axis (1 Hz, 10 Hz etc.) and not the y-axis (what's my concern). Maybe I haven't made it clear in the question, but both signals are defined over the time (seconds, x-axis) and their resolution is 0.001 s (= 1 ms). The PDF doesn't have (as far as I understand it) a measure for its y-axis (aside from probability), but the rectangle is given in Hz.

Comment: Although I also read, that after the normalization of the distribution to an area = 1 (i.e. calculating the PDF), the measure of the y-axis becomes "probability/resolution of the x-axis", so in my case "probability/1 ms". My aim is, that the convolution result has seconds on its x-axis (1 ms resolution) and Hz on its y-axis.

Comment: f and g need not be normalized in order to apply convolution. However if indeed one or the other or both are normalized, then we can say something about the normalization of convoluton(f, g). If both are normalized to 1, then convolution(f, g) is also normalized to 1. After thinking about it a minute, I believe if only one is normalized, then convolution(f, g) has total mass = the total mass of the non-normalized other one. I think you can show this by integrating convolution(f, g) over the real line. Maybe you will give it a try.

Comment: @RobertDodier OK, to see if I understood you correctly ... Do you want to say, that if the probability mass function (PMF/mass) of my not normalized rectangle f(t) equals the PMF of my convolution result conv(f,g), I successfully regained the measuring unit (1/s) of f(t)? This would then be due to the fact, that the mass of the normalized signal g(t) = 1. I checked that in my program und can confirm that the sum/PMF over all values of conv(f,g) is identical to the sum/PMF of f(t) when g(t) is a PMF.

Comment: When I transfer these thoughts now to the PDF approach, that would mean I have to multiply conv(f,g) with my time resolution in order to gain identical masses (I checked that). And that's only logical, because as I calculated the PDF, I normalized it also to its time resolution. The division and multiplication before and after the convolution would cancel each other out and that would mean I effectively calculate a PMF. But that on the other hand seems not logical. I thought it's only possible/allowed to calculate a PMF if I use natural numbers for the calculation of my distribution?

Comment: Well, mass functions are definable on any countable set, and countable sets are isomorphic to the integers. Which is a long-winded way of saying it doesn't matter, just relabel your points 0, 1, 2, 3, ....